# Binding dom-change event to nested child template even when parent template is dom-if false

Tags: javascript, dom, polymer, polymer-1.0

I have a `parent template which is a dom-if` and `set to false at start`. It has a `child template which is a dom-repeat`. I want to `bind a dom-change event to child template` however when i try to do it in ready function `it says cannot find addEventListener of undefined`. how to bind a dom-change event in this case.

```
this.$.level.addEventListener("dom-change", function (event) {    
    console.log(event);
});
```

here is the html for

```
<template is="dom-repeat" id="levels" items="{{parentNodes}}">
    <template is="dom-repeat" id="level" items="{{item.children}}"> //want to bind dom-change event to this however it is not there on dom ready
        //some html here
    </template>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since level is within a a `dom-repeat` and a `dom-if`, `this.$.level` alias does not exist. You can use `this.$$('#level')` AFTER it has been inserted onto the page (if needs to be true and the repeat run).

You will have a problem where you could end up with multiple ids "level" so you should have `id={{someFunc(index)}}"` and that function that returns `"level"+index` or select them via a class instead.

Comment: How do we check for "AFTER it has been inserted" we need to keep binding unbinding the events on the true false condition? is thats the correct way of doing it in polymer?

Comment: I suppose you can have a dom-change event on your top level template tag, and then add and remove event listeners as that changes, but really, the best way of doing this depends on your code. I cannot comment on truly best ways of doing things since I dont know your code. The point is if you try to search for that ID before it exists, it wont work.